# How to local store a useState data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this hook

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
```

How can I local store this data so when you refresh the page data in useState saves

Answer (score 0):

you might store the data in the localStorage, but when you use the `setFolders()` function, you must update it in localStorage.

Your code should look like this:

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('folders')) || [])
const setFoldersStorage = (new) => { setFolders(new); localStorage.setItem('folders', JSON.stringify(new)); }
```

when you want to update **folders**, you use the **setFoldersStorage()**

Comment: it's erroring out Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @ZAPE oh sorry, my bad, should be like that: `const [folders, setFolders] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('folders') || "[]"))`
The error happens because if you don't have a field 'folders' in LS, you try to parse Null in JSON.parse(), this causes the Error

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieve the initial data from the localStorage
const [folders, setFolders] = useState(
  () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folders") || "[]"));

// store the value into the localStorage whenever folders is updated
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("folders", JSON.stringify(folders));
}, [folders]);
```

You can also create a custom hook so you can reuse it

```
function useStateLs(initValue, lsKey) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(lsKey) || JSON.stringify(initValue))
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(lsKey, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

const [folders, setFolders] = useStateLs([], "folders");
```

Comment: All of the variants are erroring out Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: I don't get any error, maybe you missed one parenthesis after the `getItem` => `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(lsKey)) || initValue`

Comment: nope, i actually copied your code and it doesn't work

Comment: actually,  `useEffect` takes an array as the second argument so basically its `, [value]` instead of `, value`

Comment: I also tried my code on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1c1ukd and I don't get any error

Answer (score 0):

So mainly, what you need is to set an item to the local storage every time the `folders` state changes and at the same time update `setFolders` every time the component re-renders.

```
  function MyComponent(){
    const [folders, setFolders] = useState([])

      // update setFolders with the local storage data
      useEffect(() => {
        setFolders(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('folders')))
      }, [])

      // save folders state in local storage when it changes
      useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('folders', folders)
      }, [folders])

    return <>{folders}</>
  }
```

Comment: it's erroring out Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: can you share your code?